# Swift. Make map view annotation smoothly transition to new annotationView

Tags: swift, animation, annotations, location, mkmapview

I have a mapView with a moving annotation. Say it shows a car moving along a road. The user can change their transport mode from car to motorbike. I can't get the annotation to smoothly transition from a car image (of type CarAnnotation) to a bike annotation (BikeAnnotation). I've tried various ways of chaining animations in the didUpdateLocations method but what generally happens is the old (car) annotation disappears quickly, and the new (bike) annotation takes a few seconds to appear and seems to animate in from a slight random offset direction (not from the position the old removed annotation was just removed from). How can I animate gracefully?

```
    /// Main locmanager delegate method. sent when USER moves according to vars in loc man setup ie .best & 10m
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    // -----------------------
    // Checks and setup

    // check user
    guard let uid = uid else { return }

    // check location not nil
    guard let userLocation = locations.last else { return }

    // check accuracy. if first run (userLoc=nil) let code continue
    let accuracy = userLocation.horizontalAccuracy
    if self.userLocation != nil && (accuracy < 0 || accuracy > reqAccuracy) {
        return // wait for next didUpdateLoc call
    }

    // set userlocation prop
    self.userLocation = userLocation

    //TODO: should allow user to scroll map to look at different area, with button & timer to return
    // should have button to allow to return to current location or automatically return
    // switch to indicate user is zooming, panning needed. should only set region if the user has not panned away

    // set map region
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(userLocation.coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    // -----------------------
    // Create annotations

    // check mode
    guard let mode = self.transportMode else { return } // ider transport mode

    // create new or reused ann
    let ann = Annotation.createOrUpdateAnnotation(uid: uid, user: .ider(mode: mode), userLocation: userLocation, prevAnn: annotations[uid])

    // set status (for tint). also done in idReq status var observer
    if let annStatusString = self.idRequest?.latestStatus?.desc() {
        let annStatus = _IDRequestStatus.init(rawValue: annStatusString)
        ann.requestStatus = annStatus
    }

    // check if ann type (transport mode proxy) has changed from prev ann
    if let prevAnn = annotations[uid], !ann.isEqual(prevAnn) {
        // add new ann to map

        // animate removal of prev ann view
        let prevAnnView = mapView.view(for: prevAnn)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            prevAnnView?.alpha = 0
            self.mapView.addAnnotation(ann)
        }) { (finished) in
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation(prevAnn)
            prevAnnView?.alpha = 1.0 //reset alpha for view reuse
        }
    } else {
        // same ann type (transport mode proxy)

        // add to map
        mapView.addAnnotation(ann)

        // animate to new location
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
            ann.annLocation = userLocation  // update the cllocation of the userAnn to trigger movement
        }
    }

    // -----------------------
    // save ann

    // save to dic
    self.annotations[uid] = ann

    // save to database
    saveIderLocationToGeoFirestore()

} // didUpdateLocation
```